# Comparing preset values to values from an inventory log?

Tags: python, parsing, reporting

I need to check values in a inventory log, compare those strings to preset values and if they do not match, report an error.

These are the values that all inventory logs should have:

+Hardware information

Processor               : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 0 @ 1.90GHz

Memory                  : 65493MB

Controller Slot         : 0

BIOS                    : 3.0b 03/28/2014 3.2

IPMI FW rev             : 2.24

So how can I read in these values, compare them to these values: 3.0b,2.24, etc. and if they do not match report an error? I am working with this as of now.

```
 i = 0
while i < len( inventory_lines):
    m = re.search( '(^ERROR:\s+.*)', inventory_lines[i] )
    i += 1
    if m:
        arack = findRack( Lab, Rack )
        aslot = findSlot( arack, Slot )
        append_uniq_scanIssues( aslot, m.group(1) )
        print '%s SCAN ISSUES: %s' % ( linenum(), m.group(1) )
```

Comment: Check out the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module. It would also help if you added to your question a sample of your CSV data.

Comment: You code doesn't really make sense compared to your question.  What is that regex trying to do?

Comment: @mhawke I did the block above the code is the CSV stuff.

Comment: @JamieCockburn the regex is getting the string from the inventory logs and placing them beside the error message or an automated message that is later in the code I am not 100 percent sure.

Comment: @Intern_Bob Ah, then that is not CSV data (CSV mean Comma Separated Values).  Are you saying that your data is formatted exactly as you've shown?  And if so, are there multiple such entries in a single file?

Comment: @JamieCockburn Yes, what I am showing you is that is exactly is formatted. I need to parse because I am doing this to a lot of inventory logs then compare then report.

Comment: @Intern_Bob your data is not CSV, the csv module will not help you with this (unless you convert it to CSV first)

Comment: You've not answered my other question, is it multiple records per file?  If yes, is there some particular string that all records begin with (i.e. is `+Hardware information` at the start of each record).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your csv looks like this:

```
Processor,Memory,Controller Slot, BIOS,IPMI FW rev
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 0 @ 1.90GHz,65493MB,0,3.0b 03/28/2014 3.2,2.24
...
```

You want something like this:

```
import csv

good_values = {
    'Processor': 'Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 0 @ 1.90GHz',
    'Memory':, '65493MB'
    'Controller Slot': '0',
    'BIOS': '3.0b 03/28/2014 3.2',
    'IPMI FW rev': '2.24',
    }

for i, line in enumerate(csv.DictReader(open("INVENTORY FILE"))):
    if line != good_values:
        print "Error: on line %s" % (i)
```